# Using find_if on map containing shared_ptr increases ref count

Tags: c++

I'm creating a program which has a map containing shared_ptr's. And when I try to find an element in it with `std::find_if`, the reference count of the shared_ptr increases. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>


int main(void)
{
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<int>> map;
    map[1] = std::make_shared<int>(3);
    map[2] = std::make_shared<int>(5);
    map[4] = std::make_shared<int>(-2);

    auto it = std::find_if(map.begin(), map.end(),
        [](const std::pair<int, std::shared_ptr<int>> &elem) {
            std::cout << "find_if: " << elem.second.use_count() << std::endl;
            return *elem.second == 5;
        });

    std::cout << "main: " << it->second.use_count() << std::endl;
}
```

With this code I get the output of

```
find_if: 2
find_if: 2
main: 1
```

and I'm not sure if the reference count increase is proper behaviour.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the type of the parameter of your lambda

```
const std::pair<int, std::shared_ptr<int>> &
```

...this does not correspond to [`std::map<<int, std::shared_ptr<int>>>::value_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) (you are missing the `const` for the key type).

Thus, in order to call your lambda, a temporary object of type `std::pair<int, std::shared_ptr<int>>` has to be constructed from the `std::pair<const int, std::shared_ptr<int>>` stored in the `std::map`.

When this object is constructed, the `shared_ptr` is copied, so its reference counter has to be incremented.

If you change the type of the argument to

```
const std::pair<const int, std::shared_ptr<int>> &
```

...the problem disapears. You could also use `const auto&` instead of the full type here.

<sub><sup>1</sup> If you use a non-`const` reference here, you'll get a compiler error because you cannot initialize a reference of type `std::pair<int, std::shared_ptr<int>>` from a `std::pair<const int, std::shared_ptr<int>>`, but a `const`-reference allow a temporary to be used instead.</sub>